# Bootstrap grid - half fluid, half normal container layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need some help with building a layout. [Check out the image for the wanted layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkPWq.png). The green area displays the carousel, while the blue areas are not part of the carousel.

In this layout, it is important that the green area is aligned to the left of the screen and that the blue area's keep contained in the container, otherwise I could have easily used the container-fluid class.

So, does anybody have a simple answer to this?

Comment: That's a tough nut to crack without js... I don't think you really want a fluid container, as defined in Bootstrap. A fluid container in Bootstrap causes all (underlying) columns to be fluid as well, so they can be any width. In your case, you want everything to be non-fluid, with the additional requirement of one grid cell being lined up to the right of the 8th column, but expanding to the end of the screen on the left. You might have to do some js magic to figure out a dynamic negative left margin for this one.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: For now I just place the carousel within the container, because I couldn't find and think of anything..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works pretty well for half fluid, half not.  Im my case I wanted a map on the left half, going right up to the browser edge, with what will end up being a contact form on the right hand side, but not wider than the standard `container` class width.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid relative">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 absolute left-half" style="background-color: #E2F1FC; height: 400px">
                        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
                        <p>
                            Duis at hendrerit erat, non interdum urna. Praesent metus odio, laoreet sed ultrices et, egestas
                            non erat. In tincidunt et purus a convallis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean turpis
                            justo, lobortis ac gravida et, sagittis eu est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
                            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis convallis est et placerat gravida. Cras quis
                            quam vestibulum, mollis sapien a, mollis libero. Donec ut massa ultricies, porttitor erat quis,
                            pretium massa. Donec placerat egestas pulvinar.
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.relative{
    position: relative;
}
.absolute{
    position: absolute;
}
.left-half{
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JohnHalsey/z3menav7/2/

You could easily add media breaks if you wanted it to stack on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

@John Halsey 's solution updated for BS4:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.left-half {
  padding-left:0 !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid position-relative">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 position-absolute left-half">
          <div id="map-canvas" style="background-color: #E2F1FC; height: 400px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 offset-6">
          <p>
            Duis at hendrerit erat, non interdum urna. Praesent metus odio, laoreet sed ultrices et, egestas non erat. In tincidunt et purus a convallis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean turpis justo, lobortis ac gravida et, sagittis eu est. Pellentesque
            habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis convallis est et placerat gravida. Cras quis quam vestibulum, mollis sapien a, mollis libero. Donec ut massa ultricies, porttitor erat quis, pretium massa.
            Donec placerat egestas pulvinar.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8>
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4>
         <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4>
                    ...
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4>
                    ...
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have sollution for col-__-6 cells...

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-z-index-fix">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.col-z-index-fix{
    z-index: 10;
}
```

In fact you dont need to use .col-z-index-fix until you want to set position: relative/fixed/absolute to the inner .container or .row div.

Answer (score 0):

I had been here in this post and others looking for a solution for bootstrap 4 and I didn't found anything. So now I have a solution for the problem to mix container layout and container fluid layout. Maybe this one can help someone, one day!

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 220px; /* depending of your code */
}

.example-left:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -15px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6; /* If you want to use color*/
}

.example-right:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -15px;
  background-image: url('https://www.sciencenews.org/sites/default/files/2019/03/main/articles/032719_lg_blackhole_feat.jpg'); /* If you want to use image*/

  /* depending of your propouse */
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="example example-left">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-6">
        <p>Content Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example example-right">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Content Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```